# Does ubuntu Gnome have unity with it?

Tags: 16.04, ubuntu-gnome

So, I was using ubuntu 15.10 for a LONG time, but I got bored with unity. I then downloaded [ubuntu Gnome](https://ubuntugnome.org/). Now, I don't really love unity, but i DO want to like to work on that for sometimes. So my main question is : does ubuntu Gnome have unity pre-installed on it or not?

Comment: No, it does not.

Answer (score 3):

NO, it does NOT. That's why it's called Ubuntu Gnome! Only Ubuntu has Unity preinstalled. That's why all Ubuntu flavors have different names and only ONE desktop environment preinstalled. So you don't confuse them up.

Answer (score 3):

No it does not but you have some options:

1. I myself use an LTS as my main operating system (the one I boot into) and have instances for the latest operating systems I use.  So in virtualbox I have a 16.04 that I use for daily use. Watch movies, series while commuting. And another few for work related things (I have a copy of all the systems my clients work on).

   Biggest advantages compared to the other methods I will list: deleting an OS is easy. Copying an OS is easy. Running 2 or more is easy (but a resource hog ;) ). Making a backup is easy.

   Example on how this looks:

[image]

2. Create a multi boot. You can have Ubuntu Gnome and Ubuntu itself and tons of operating systems next to each other sharing a data partition so you can watch video's, code software, listen to music that is on that partition with all of the operating systems.
3. You can also install multiple desktops on the same machine and pick the one you want during login.

Here is an old image with Gnome, Cinnamon, Steam OS and Ubuntu:

[image]